# how to deal with map of map?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/159/A

To find the solution, I thought of presenting the input by making a map of map.
And for this input my map should appear like this:

#### m["vasya"]={{"petya",1}}

#### m["petya"]={{"vasya",2}}

#### m["anya"]={{"ivan",2}}

#### m["ivan"]={{"anya",4}}

Below is my code.

and my assignment code:
`// m[s1]=(ii(s2,t));`
is wrong

my question is how can i assign to the map of map?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){    
    typedef map<string, int> ii;
    map<string, ii> m;

    int n,d;
    cin>>n>>d;

    string s1,s2,t;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>s1>>s2>>t;
        // m[s1]=(ii(s2,t));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make a more descriptive typedef than `ii`, but specifically you just want to add a new key-value pair into the map:

```
m[s1].insert(std::make_pair(s2, t));
```

Or if you want to split it up for clarity:

```
ii& submap = m[s1];
submap[s2] = t;
```

Or, if C++11 is available to you, exactly what you expressed in your question:

```
m[s1] = {{s2, t}};
```

Comment: That gives me this error after modifying,,,,

IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exists

Comment: @Abuzanona that's because you defined `t` as a `string` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
m[s1][s2] = t;
```

I'm assuming you meant `int t;` rather than `string t;` since the last type in your map is `int`.